# Автоматический перезапуск dovecot в Debian

Tags: debian, dovecot

Здравствуйте. На сервере периодически зависает сервис dovecot, в результате чего перестает работать IMAP.
Пытаюсь сделать автоматический перезапуск сервиса при его зависании.
Нашел такой пример для FreeBSD:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/find /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ -type file | xargs -I$ sh -c "($  2>&1 | grep -q -v status) \
      && exit ; ($ status > /dev/null) && exit ; $ start"
```

Помогите сделать аналогично для Debian. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, приведённый скрипт к программе *dovecot* не имеет никакого отношения — он проверяет статус **всех** демонов, старт-стоповые скрипты которых находятся в указанном каталоге (понятно, что, согласно стандартам [*lsb*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) это будет каталог `/etc/init.d`, а не `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`, как в примере).

для одного демона полный аналог найденного вами скрипта будет таким:

```
# /etc/init.d/dovecot status >/dev/null || /etc/init.d/dovecot start
```

во-вторых, он всего лишь запускает демонов, старт-стоповые скрипты которых имеют параметр *status* и при вызове с этим параметром возвращающие результат «не ноль». т.е., запускает **неработающие** демоны.

если у вас программа *dovecot* действительно прекращает работу, то такой скрипт подойдёт. а если, как вы написали, программа «зависает» (как я понимаю, программа продолжает выполняться, но не отвечает на сетевые запросы), то данный скрипт не поможет — ведь проверять вам надо не наличие процесса(-ов), а его работоспособность.

---

самый правильный, с моей точки зрения, ответ: надо выявить и устранить причины «зависания», а не исправлять их последствия.

Comment: Если программа перестает отвечать на сетевые запросы - то может есть резон сделать таймаут, и если за это время ответ не пришел - сделать /etc/init.d/dovecot stop && !:0 start      ??

Comment: @Crystal, *сделать ...* — да можно и короче — просто restart.